# 2 triangle button overlapping only CSS

Tags: css, button

I'm programming a subreddit so I can only modify the CSS, and I'm trying to create 2 triangular button and place it like it forms a square. The point is that I want them to be separated and both clickable, and when I overlap like this

[triangle buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUOLe.png)

The first one becomes unclickable because of the `overflow: hidden` on the second triangle container.

This is my code:

```css
.submit-link .morelink {
   
    height:120px;
    width: 120px;
    border:0;
    position:relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-image: none; 
    float: left;
}


.sidebox submit submit-link {
    overflow: hidden;
}


.submit-link .morelink .login-required{

    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100px;
    right: 102px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 200px;
    background:red;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0;
    transform-origin: 100% 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.submit-link .morelink .nub {
    
    background-image: url(%%linkicon%%);
    background-size: 100%;
    width: 60px;
    background-position: none;
    opacity: 0;
}

.submit-text .morelink {
    
    margin-left: -110px;
    height:120px;
    width: 120px;
    border:0;
    position:relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-image: none; 
    float: left;
    background: none;
    margin-top: 10px;
   
    
}

.sidebox submit submit-text{
     overflow: hidden;
     

}

.submit-text .morelink .login-required{
    
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 250px;
    height: 200px;
    background:red;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0;
    transform-origin: 100% 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    
}


.submit-text .morelink .nub {
    
    background-image: url(%%texticon%%);
    background-size: 100%;
    width: 60px;
    background-position: none;
    opacity: 0;
   
}

.morelink:hover, .mlh {
    border-color: #879eb4;
    background-image: none;
}

.spacer .submit-text.morelink {
    float: left;
    width: 140px;
}

.titlebox {
 
        padding-top: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="side">
  <div class="spacer">
    <div id="ad_main_top" class="ad300x250">
    </div> 
   </div>
  <div class="spacer">
    <div class="sidebox submit submit-link">
      <div class="morelink">
        <a href="https://www.reddit.com/r/paladinsideas/submit" data-event-action="submit" data-type="subreddit" data-event-detail="link" class="login-required access-required" target="_top">Invia un nuovo link</a>
        <div class="nub">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="spacer">
    <div class="sidebox submit submit-text">
      <div class="morelink">
        <a href="https://www.reddit.com/r/paladinsideas/submit?selftext=true" data-event-action="submit" data-type="subreddit" data-event-detail="self" class="login-required access-required" target="_top"></a>
        <div class="nub">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="spacer"><div class="titlebox">

</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can solve your problem:

```
.morelink a {
    z-index: 50;   /*** 1 ***/
}
.morelink:hover, .morelink:hover a {
    z-index: 1;    /*** 2 ***/
}
.morelink a:hover {
    z-index: 100;  /*** 3 ***/
}
```

1. We set the default z-index of the anchor to 50
2. We set the `z-index` of the container (and the anchor) to 50, once the container is hovered.
3. If the anchor itself is hovered - we set it's z-index to 100.

Here is a working snippet:

```css
.submit-link .morelink {
   
    height:120px;
    width: 120px;
    border:0;
    position:relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-image: none; 
    float: left;
}


.sidebox submit submit-link {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.morelink a {
  z-index: 50;
}
.morelink:hover, .morelink:hover a {
  z-index: 1;
}
.morelink a:hover {
  z-index: 100;
}
.submit-link .morelink .login-required{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100px;
    right: 102px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 200px;
    background:red;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0;
    transform-origin: 100% 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.submit-link .morelink .nub {
    
    background-image: url(%%linkicon%%);
    background-size: 100%;
    width: 60px;
    background-position: none;
    opacity: 0;
}

.submit-text .morelink {
    
    margin-left: -110px;
    height:120px;
    width: 120px;
    border:0;
    position:relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-image: none; 
    float: left;
    background: none;
    margin-top: 10px;
   
    
}

.sidebox submit submit-text{
     overflow: hidden;
     

}

.submit-text .morelink .login-required{
    
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 250px;
    height: 200px;
    background:red;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0;
    transform-origin: 100% 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    
}


.submit-text .morelink .nub {
    
    background-image: url(%%texticon%%);
    background-size: 100%;
    width: 60px;
    background-position: none;
    opacity: 0;
   
}

.morelink:hover, .mlh {
    border-color: #879eb4;
    background-image: none;
}

.spacer .submit-text.morelink {
    float: left;
    width: 140px;
}

.titlebox {
 
        padding-top: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="side">
  <div class="spacer">
    <div id="ad_main_top" class="ad300x250">
    </div> 
   </div>
  <div class="spacer">
    <div class="sidebox submit submit-link">
      <div class="morelink">
        <a href="https://www.reddit.com/r/paladinsideas/submit" data-event-action="submit" data-type="subreddit" data-event-detail="link" class="login-required access-required" target="_top">Invia un nuovo link</a>
        <div class="nub">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="spacer">
    <div class="sidebox submit submit-text">
      <div class="morelink">
        <a href="https://www.reddit.com/r/paladinsideas/submit?selftext=true" data-event-action="submit" data-type="subreddit" data-event-detail="self" class="login-required access-required" target="_top"></a>
        <div class="nub">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="spacer"><div class="titlebox">

</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use `transform` and tune `transform-origin` to your needs.

example:

```css
div {
  width: 5vw;
  height: 5vw;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  position: relative;
  border: solid 1em transparent;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px;
  background:turquoise
}

div a {
  position: absolute;
  top: -2vw;
  left: -2vw;
  right: -2vw;
  bottom: -2vw;
  background: red;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform-origin: 80% -15%
}

div a + a {
  background: yellow;
  z-index: 1;
  transform-origin: 30% 120%
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#one" title="one"></a>
  <a href="two" title="two"></a>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/LRJKab